# How do you move more than a single item with PowerShell at once?

Tags: powershell

When I try to run:

```
mv test.txt test2.txt test-files
```

Returns the error:

```
Move-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '.\test-files\'.
At line:1 char:1
+ mv .\test.txt .\test2.txt .\test-files\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

However, if I simply move the files one at a time with

```
mv test.txt test-files
mv test2.txt test-files
```

Then it moves the files, but this seems tedious if I had more than two files.

Is there any possible way to move multiple files at once to a specific location?

I've tried mv t*.txt test-files which works, but the files I want to actually move are index.html and style.css

Comment: Use `,` to pass the first two arguments as an array `mv test.txt,test2.txt test-files`

Comment: I feel so dumb now, thanks for the answer. I got thrown off since bash doesn't use commas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: As your error message reveals, `mv` is a built-in alias of PowerShell's [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) cmdlet (albeit only on Windows) - see the bottom section for why this is problematic and why it's better to use the **`mi`** alias.

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71871305/45375) provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

**Multiple source paths must be passed as an *array* to `Move-Item`**'s `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` parameter, which with directly specified paths **requires separating them with `,`**:

```sh
# Note the "," separating the source file names.
Move-Item -LiteralPath test.txt, test2.txt -Destination test-files
```

I've used *named* arguments above, i.e. I've preceded the arguments with the names of their target parameters.

PowerShell also supports *positional* parameter binding:

```sh
Move-Item test.txt, test2.txt test-files
```

This works, but note that it isn't fully equivalent to the above, because the first positional argument - `test.txt, test2.txt` binds to the `-Path` parameter, not `-LiteralPath`:

- It doesn't make a difference here, because the file names at hand contain no [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) characters.
- However, if your literal file names happen to contain `[` (e.g., `test[2].txt`), binding to `-Path` wouldn't work as expected.

---

##### Discovery of whether a cmdlet's parameters support arrays:

You can discover whether a given parameter supports arrays by looking at its **[syntax diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax)**, which are part of the brief help that is displayed when you pass the **standard `-?` switch**; you can also display them in isolation with **`Get-Command -Syntax Move-Item`**, for instance.

Using [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help), you can even ask for **details about specific parameters**, using `-Path` as an example:

```sh
PS> Get-Help Move-Item -Parameter Path

-Path <System.String[]>

    Specifies the path to the current location of the items. The default is the current directory. Wildcard characters are permitted.
    
    Required?                    true
    Position?                    0
    Default value                Current directory
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName, ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  true
```

`<System.String[]>` denotes the parameter's type, which in this case is an array (`[]` of `System.String` (`[string]`) instances. In other words: **`[]` following a parameter type implies that arrays are supported.**

However, **a given cmdlet can choose to *also* support passing multiple arguments *individually*** to an array-typed parameter (of necessity only *one* parameter can support this per cmdlet), declared with a [`[Parameter()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute) attribute whose `ValueFromRemainingArguments` property is set to `$true`:

An example is [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), whose (one and only positional) `-InputObject` parameter is typed `System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]`, but also has `ValueFromRemainingArguments` set, so that the following two calls are equivalent:<sup>[1]</sup>

```sh
# Single array argument that directly binds to -InputObject
Write-Output 1, 2, 3

# Multiple arguments that implicitly bind collected in an array to -InputObject
Write-Output 1 2 3
```

**Note**:

- Unfortunately, **the help does *not* reveal the presence of `ValueFromRemainingArguments`** - neither in the parameter's detailed view with `Get-Help ... -Parameter ...`, nor, typically, in a parameter's description.
- While **programmatic discovery is possible**, it is nontrivial:

  ```sh
  # -> 'InputObject'
  (Get-Command Write-Output).Parameters.Values.
    Where({ $_.Attributes.ValueFromRemainingArguments -contains $true }).Name
  ```

Another example is [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host), whose `-Object` parameter behaves the same way. However, what is unusual about this parameter is that its type is `-Object <System.Object>`, i.e. it doesn't explicitly reveal that it accepts *arrays*; however, it does; technically, this possible due to `System.Object` being capable of storing *any* data type, including arrays (collections). It is only the plural in the parameter's *description* that hints at the fact that `-Object` accepts arrays: "Objects to display in the host."

---

##### Alias-naming considerations:

That `mv` is a built-in alias for `Move-Item` (on Windows only)<sup>[2]</sup> is problematic. More broadly, **all aliases named for *internal commands of a different shell*** (e.g., `cmd.exe`'s `dir`) or, as in this case, **for *external programs*** (possibly a different platform's) **are problematic**, because the syntax of these commands / programs usually differs fundamentally from PowerShell's syntax.

- Case in point: the `mv` command in your question *would* work with the Unix-platform `/bin/mv` utility.

It is **better to use PowerShell *own* aliases**, whose names are formed methodically from the [approved verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) part of the command being aliased, with each approved verb having its official abbreviation, e.g., `m` for `Move-`. The abbreviation for the *noun* part isn't standardized, but using the initial letter stands to reason, e.g. `i` for `Item`.

- In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you can discover the verb abbreviation via [`Get-Verb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-verb) (output column `AliasPrefix`), e.g., `Get-Verb Move`; in *Windows PowerShell* you'll need to consult the "approved verb" link above.

And, indeed, `mi` is another built-in alias for `Move-Item`, as the following discovery command based on [`Get-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-alias) reveals:

```sh
PS> Get-Alias -Definition Move-Item

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           mi -> Move-Item                                               
Alias           move -> Move-Item                                             
Alias           mv -> Move-Item      # WINDOWS ONLY
```

- The big advantage of such aliases - aside from not pretending to be something they're not - is that their methodic naming makes it easier to remember and possibly even guess their names; e.g., `gc` for `Get-Content` and, as `Get-Alias -Definition Get-Alias` reveals, `gal` for `Get-Alias`.
- Name conflicts with external programs can still occur, but are less likely. E.g. `sc` for `Set-Content` shadows the native `sc.exe` utility (for controlling services), which is the reason it was - somewhat controversially - removed from PowerShell (Core).

---

<sup>[1] Due to the bug described in [GitHub issue #5122](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5122), the commands aren't fully equivalent if you also use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output)'s `-NoEnumerate` switch in PowerShell (Core) 7+, though the difference will rarely matter in practice: `Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2, 3` emits a single `[object[]]` instance, as expected, whereas `Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1 2 3` unexpectedly outputs a `[System.Collections.Generic[object]]` instance. In *Windows PowerShell*, there is a different, more severe bug: Only the form `Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2, 3` produces an `[object[]]` array as a single output object, as expected; by contrast, the forms `Write-Output -NoEnumerate  1 2 3` and even `Write-Output -NoEnumerate -InputObject 1, 2, 3` effectively *ignore* the `-NoEnumerate` switch and therefore output the elements one by one.</sup>

<sup>[2] On Unix-like platforms, the `mv` alias isn't defined, so as not to shadow the external, platform-native `/bin/mv` program.</sup>